# Why MAUI App Splash Screen shows centred in both Android and IOS APP

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, maui

We are planing to start the development with MAUI for Mobile Apps in our company.

SplashScreen on Android App shows centred on the screen. Also I have read the Microsoft article about the [Maui SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=ios) and I have been searching for a solution on this. It would be great if we get a solution which covers the entire screen. I got the information from this [Developer Community](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10669)

I have tried the sample maui project and placing the SpashScreen to the mauiSplashScreen entry in CSProj.

Output from Android APP :

[image: SplashScreen centred in Android app]

PNG Image used for SplashScreen :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  If you want it to fill the screen, there is a section in the docs you linked to on using the `BaseSize` attribute

Comment: What's your target android version? You can't make the image fill the splash screen on the android 12 and higher.